# How can I only allow a function A to be called only after function B is called?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code class:

```
class A {
   public:
      int number;
      vector<int> powers;

      A () {
         number = 5;
         powers.resize(100);
      }

      long long getPower(int x) {
        return powers[x];
      }

      void precompute() {
         powers[0] = 1;
         for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            powers[i] = powers[i - 1] * number;
         }
       }
};
```

In the class `A`, we have a vector called `powers` and an integer `number` with the property that `powers[k]` stores the quantity `numbers^k` after the `precompute()` function has been called. If we want to answer several queries of the form "Compute `numbers^x` for some integer `0 <= x < 100`", it makes sense to precompute all of these powers and return them when we need them as a constant-time operation (note: this is not a problem that I am actually facing. I have made this problem up for the sake of an example. Please ignore the fact that `numbers^x` would exceed the maximum value of a `long long`).

However, there is one issue: the user must have called the `precompute()` function before calling the `getPower()` function.

This leads me to the following question: Is there some nice way to enforce the constraint that some function `A` can only be called after function `B` is called? Of course, one could just use a `flag` variable, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this so that it becomes a compile-time error.

Another option would be to always call the `precompute()` function in the constructor, but this may not be an optimal solution if we weren't always going to call `precompute()` in the first place. If calling `precompute()` is a sufficiently expensive (computationally), then this method would not be preferable.

I would prefer getting a compile-time error over a runtime error, but I am open to all approaches. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Or you could do the computation the first time `getPower` is called.  Then the user doesn't have to worry about it at all.

Comment: You're right. Not sure why I didn't think of this :)

Comment: Doing it in getPower would require a flag or check. Why not do it in the constructor?

Comment: @STF_ZBR Do you mean calling `precompute` in the constructor? If so, I want to avoid doing so because the `precompute` function may be computationally expensive.

Comment: I don't see how the compiler can know if a function has been called already. But either a flag of your own or the `std::call_once` system will do the trick, I guess.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you. I didn't know about `std::call_once`. It looks very helpful.

Comment: @Ekeshkumar I definitely understand not wanting it in the constructor. I only offer it as a suggestion. But, depending on use of the class, it may make sense.

Comment: @STF_ZBR I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: You can split it into two classes. The `ABuilder` and the `A`. `ABuilder` has a method called `precompute` that returns an `A`. The `getPower` method is on the `A` object. Therefore the only way to call `getPower` is to have an `A`, and the only way to get an `A` is to call `precompute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to call the `precompute` function in the constructor of `class A`.

Alternatively, as has already been suggested in the comments section, you could make the function `getPower` check a flag which specifies whether `precompute` has already been called, and if not, either perform the call itself or print an error message.

I can't think of a way to force this check to be done at compile time. However, if you want to eliminate this run-time check from release builds, you could use conditional compilation so that these checks are only included in debug builds, for example by using the [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) macro or by using preprocessor directives, like this:

```
// note that NDEBUG is normally only defined in release builds, not debug builds

#ifdef NDEBUG
//check for flag here and print error message if flag has unexpected value
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, to enforce timing dependency, you might make the dependency explicit.

For example:

```
class PowerGetter
{
    friend class A;
    const A& a;
public:
    long long getPower(int x) {
        return a.powers[x];
    }
};

class A {
public:
    int number = 5;
    std::vector<int> powers = std::vector<int>(100);

    A() = default;

    PowerGetter precompute() {
        powers[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            powers[i] = powers[i - 1] * number;
        }
        return {*this};
    }
};
```

Then to call `getPower` we need a `PowerGetter` which can only be obtained by calling `precompute` first.

For that contrived example, simpler would be to place initialization in `A` though.